# Why APK file can not be generated for Expo SDK 32? Any alternative?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a very old react native application written on Expo using SDK version 32. Unfortunately, we don't have the time and resource to migrate to the latest version of the SDK (40).

So, right now, we struggle with an issue which reproduces on an Android. One of our screens has a background video (implemented with Expo Video component) and two buttons over it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, Text, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Video } from 'expo';

const defaultVideoSource = require('../content/videos/be.mp4');

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            backgroundOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
            loaded: false,
            videoHeight: height,
            videoWidth: width,
        };
    }

    async componentWillMount() { }

    // this is called from the video::onLoad()
    fadeInVideo = () => {
        const { backgroundOpacity } = this.state;
        setTimeout(() => {
            Animated.spring(backgroundOpacity, {
                toValue: 1
            }).start();
        }, 400);
    };

    render() {
        const { backgroundOpacity, loaded, videoHeight, videoWidth } = this.state;

        if (!loaded) { return <AppLoading />; }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.background}>
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[
                        styles.backgroundViewWrapper,
                        { opacity: backgroundOpacity }
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Video
                            isLooping
                            isMuted={false}
                            onLoad={() => this.fadeInVideo()}
                            resizeMode="cover"
                            shouldPlay
                            source= { defaultVideoSource }
                            style={{ height: videoHeight, width: videoWidth }}
                        />
                    </Animated.View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    // BUTTONS OVER THE VIDEO
                </View>
            </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // ...
});
```

but for some reason, when I publish it to my Expo account and run it from there **the video freezes at a certain moment and stops playing**.

[image]

The buttons over the video are still active and functional. Like nothing happened but I need to restart the application (via Expo client app on Android) in order to start playing again. I have noticed that If I start it in a debug mode with the command:

```
expo start
```

and scan the QR code from the Expo client app **there's no freezing** of the video. So, for that reason, I would like to create a standalone file (.apk) which I can execute directly on my device without the need of using Expo client app. But, the problem here is that when I try to use the command:

```
expo build:android
```

I get an error saying:

> Unsupported SDK version: our app builders no longer support SDK
> version 32. Please, upgrade to at least SDK 36.

But, as I said, we currently don't have the time to do that because this (SDK update) would affect other components of our app that will need to be rewritten and retested. So, my question finally: **Is there any alternative for building an .apk while using SDK 32.0?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to build apps that use old expo sdks, but I'm not sure if play store will accept those old versions, there was a lot of changes around privacy policy and terms of service plus at certain point google started to require 64 bit binaries(I'm not sure if sdk 32 already had those changes). If that's the case your only option is to upgrade to supported SDK.

If you want to build that app, you can do that with turtle-cli https://www.npmjs.com/package/turtle-cli. This tools executes locally the same code that runs on expo servers, but it's not fully integrated with expo infrastructure, so you will need to provide keystore and all the passwords manually in the cli and either your expo credentials(if you use `expo publish`) or url to the js bundle (if you self-host). You will need to use old enough version of turtle-cli that still have that sdk, you can consult CHANGELOG here https://github.com/expo/turtle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md to check that.

Comment: Currently, we don't need to publish it to any store. Just have the apk and manually install it on few devices. Please, correct me if I am wrong but I guess this is the cli version that I need: https://github.com/expo/turtle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0139---2020-02-13